# Decorator flow and process

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

```
def logger(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs): #1
        print ('Arguments were: {}, {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs) #2
    return inner

def add (x,y):
    return x+y

add = logger(add)
add(1, 2)
```

Code without using `@logger`, basically replacing it with `add = logger(add)`.

```
def logger(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs): #1
        print ('Arguments were: {}, {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs) #2
    return inner

@logger
def add (x,y):
    return x+y

add(1, 2)
```

Code using `@logger`, `add = logger (add)` is removed.

Both are with the same and correct output

I'm still learning python and trying to understand how decorator works for these 2 examples.

I would like to know how the flow works. I get that `@logger` is the same as `add = logger(add)`, where the example then used `add (1,2)`. This means that `add(1,2) = logger(add(1,2))`?

However, if this is the case, why does it not work when I try `logger(add(1,2))`?

Basically I'm trying to combine

```
add = logger(add)
add(1,2)
```

to something like

```
logger(add(1,2))
```

which is not working. Purpose of combining it is so that I can understand example much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to 'decorate' the return value of the `add()` function call, not the `add` function *itself*.

The proper equivalent would be to use:

```
logger(add)(1, 2)
```

so use the return value of `logger()` as the function to pass the `1, 2` arguments to.

In other words, you need to substitute the right call. It may be easier to understand if you used a different name for the result of the decorator call:

```
decorated = logger(add)
decorated(1, 2)
```

and then simply substitute `decorated` for the original `logger(add)` call to:

```
logger(add)(1, 2)
```

Comment: I manage to understand how it works now with your correct equivalent. The way I perceive it is that, usually a simple function is like function (1,2), but now, if I perceive 'logger(add)' as a whole function in itself, which is why args responds to the parameters, I get it with your equivalent.

Comment: but how does args knows that it is suppose to store (1,2) instead of (func)?

Comment: @Newbie the decorator takes `func` and returns `inner`. You then call the returned  `inner()` function and it is that function that takes `*args`.

Comment: Think I got it, somehow. appreciate it. Now I just need some time to digest it.